# Rename causes "You can't open the application "XXXXX" because it may be damaged or incomplete." after updating to Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, monomac, info.plist, xamarin.mac

**Edit:** Turns out this was not a codesigning issue, so I'm updating to help anyone who runs into the same problem.

After updating a MonoMac app to Xamarin.Mac, if I changed the name of the app, I would get the message "You can't open the application "XXXXX" because it may be damaged or incomplete." It looks like it could be a codesigning issue because when I would run `codesign --verify` I would get `code object is not signed at all`.

**Original question:**

I recently updated a MonoMac app to Xamarin.Mac. In the process, something in the codesigning step seems to have changed. Specifically, now when I rename the app bundle, I get codesigning signature errors, both from the GUI and from the command line tools. It seems that if the app bundle does not match `CFBundleName`, the signature isn't valid.

For example, if I run `codesign --verify --deep -vvvv Program.app` (where `Program` matches the `CFBundleName`, I get

```
Program.app: valid on disk
Program.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

However if I change the name to `Program2.app` and run `codesign --verify --deep -vvvv Program2.app`, I get:

```
Program2.app: code object is not signed at all
```

Move it back, and I get a successful signature again.

From looking at the MonoMac app vs. the Xamarin.Mac app, there are a few differences:

1. `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` is now placed in `Contents/Resources`
2. `Info.plist` gets compiled to some binary-ish version.
3. `Contents/MonoBundle` now includes `libMonoPosixHelper.dylib`, which apparently needs signing.
4. `PkgInfo` is now included in `Contents`, with contents `APPL????`

Why do the codesigning tools care about the name of the app all of a sudden? How can I make it not care about the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was a change in the update from MonoMac to Xamarin.Mac that somehow set it to look for the executable to be named the same as the app bundle, so if you changed `Program.app` to `Program2.app`, OS X would look to run `Contents/MacOS/Program2` instead of `Contents/MacOS/Program`. I'm still not sure why the MonoMac version worked when renamed, but clearly it had some other pointer to the correct executable file.

The solution for Xamarin.Mac is to add

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>[Original app name]</string>
```

to `Info.plist`. This tells OS X where to look for the executable, and allows you to rename the app without issue.